# Plunker: Same code but unable to run - ERROR: mixed content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

I am copying the code from an plunker example but it just do not work as expected.

I take the code form this [plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/xCyDvQ/), `http://embed.plnkr.co/xCyDvQ/`

I just copy and paste in my own plunker create but as you can see, [my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4bxI8Qd8ftVfaE4D7veN?p=preview), `https://plnkr.co/edit/4bxI8Qd8ftVfaE4D7veN?p=preview` does not shown result.

Do you know what is actually wrong there? Is my setting in plunker is incorrect?

Comment: How do you mean "does not shown result."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work was that the browser blocked requests from an insecure source (aka `http://`) and the original source was `https://` causing a mixed content which was why it didn't work:

[image: Mixed content]

Thus, you must replace all `http://` scripts and sources with `https://` or those without must have `https://`.

Here's the updated [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OlhtaJZQp8bfGE3zEyqB?p=preview)

Just to let you know, the `embed.plnkr.co` domain did not block any insecure script because the domain was not `https://`.

Comment: Currently, all Plunker services should support running under both http:// and https:// though the latter is strongly encouraged. The former remains to support legacy plunks that would otherwise be affected by similar mixed content warnings in recent browsers.